# Android: When to use Button.Post?

Tags: android, button, runnable

I noticed a method called `Post` in Android's `Button` class. I was wondering what this method was for? This method takes a runnable argument, my question is when should we use this vs just having a listener bind to the click event of this button? What is the difference? Any example is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`post()` is inherited from `View`. It has nothing to do with button clicks and is not a replacement for an `OnClickListener`. `post()` is used to arrange for a `Runnable` to be executed on the main application thread, typically by some code running on a background thread.